# Node CLI Script Exits Early

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a Node JS CLI script that automates some migrations to a third-party service. I've largely avoided asynchronous methods (e.g. prefixing with `async`) as 1) I don't fully understand it in this context and 2) it hasn't been necessary for the script thus far.

Where I'm having trouble, is that I'm looping through a set of files and attempting to call a method on each entry, but the method doesn't execute before the script exits.

Here's the primary method:

```js
const migrateAll = (app, env, source) => {
  const self = this;

  fs.promises
    .readFile(config, "utf8")
    .then((contents) => {
      self.config = JSON.parse(contents);
    })
    .then(() => {
      const spaceId = self.config.applications[app].space_id;
      fs.readdir(source, "utf8", (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        files.forEach((file) => {
          console.log(chalk.yellow(`Migrating "${file}" to the "${env}" environment for "${app}"`))
          migrate(file, env, app);
        });

        process.exit();
      });
    });
};
```

The call to `migrate(file, env, app)` doesn't appear to run at all. The contents of that function are:

```js
const migrate = (space, env, migration) => {
  exec(
    `migrate ${migration} "${space}" ${env}`,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
          // A `switch` to handle errors.
        }

        process.exit();
      }
      if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        process.exit();
      }

      success(stdout);
  );
};
```

The rest of the script, in context, looks like this:

```js
const parseFlags = () => {
  process.argv.splice(2).forEach((arg) => {
    let parts = arg.split("=");

    switch (parts[0]) {
      // parse flags into variables
    }
  });

  if (all) {
    migrateAll(app, env, source);
  }

  return { app, env, source };
};

const run = () => {
  try {
    intro();
    checkSettings();
    const { app, env, source } = parseFlags();
    // continue on here if migrateAll doesn't get called
  } catch (err) {
    complain(err);
  }
};

run();
```

So, with the right flags, we call `migrateAll()` which in turn calls the `migrate` function for each file we find that needs to migrate. Some things I've noticed/tried

- The `console.log` inside of the `forEach` in `migrateAll` runs as expected
- I've tried various combinations of `await` and `async`, `.then()`, promisify, etc, but it feels like I'm throwing things at the wall just to see what sticks to no avail.

Comment: And where's the run() call?

Comment: @raina77ow sorry, added it to the code example. `run();` is just called at the bottom of the script

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You're calling async functions (`fs.promises.readFile`, `readdir` and `exec`) from within synchronous contexts. So in your script execution you have basically this:

```
 migrate() ---------------+
     |                    |
execution complete        |
     |                readFile()
   exit                   |
                         parse()
                          |
                        readdir()
                          |
                         exec()
```

You're synchronous execution completes before you finish running the async stuff.

2. You seem to spawning off a bunch of child processes to run these modules, you should instead `require` and just run them in-process
3. `exec` is not a safe way to spawn a child process as you're passing the string directly into a shell. If I as a user can control any of those three arguments I can pop a remote shell in netcat.
4. Using shorthand `migrate` is not a safe way to call a child process as it resolves from the PATH environment variable. If I have access to the runtime environment I can make `migrate` point to whatever I want.
5. Don't call `process.exit()`. The exit code you pass lets the caller or operating system know whether something went wrong. On success call `process.exit(0)`, on error use any integer that's greater than 0 and less than 256. You can assign a unique exit code to each error situation if you wish.

Try this

```js
// migrate.js
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

module.exports = async (space,env,migration) => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  let stdout = '';
  let stderr = '';
  let args = [migration,space,env];
  let cp = spawn('/absolute/path/to/migrate', args);
  cp.on('error',reject);
  cp.stdout.setEncoding('utf8').on('data',(d)=>stdout+=d);
  cp.stderr.setEncoding('utf8').on('data',(d)=>stderr+=d);
  cp.on('exit',(code,signal) => {
    if(signal)
      code = signal;
    if(code != 0) {
      console.error(stderr);
      return reject(new Error(`migrate returned exit code ${code}`));
    }
    resolve(stdout); 
  });
}).then(success); // not sure what success does, but this is equivalent to what you had


// migrate-all.js
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const migrate = require('./migrate');

module.exports = async (app,env,source) => {
  let contents = await fsp.readFile(config,'utf8');
  self.config = JSON.parse(contents);
  const spaceId = self.config.applications[app].space_id;
  let files = await fsp.readdir(source);
  for(let i in files) { // avoid async calls in .forEach loops
    let file = files[i];
    console.log(chalk.yellow(`Migrating "${file}" to the "${env}" environment for "${app}"`))
    await migrate(file, env, app);
  }
}


// index.js
const migrateAll = require('./migrate-all');

const parseFlags = async () => {
  process.argv.splice(2).forEach((arg) => {
    let parts = arg.split("=");

    switch (parts[0]) {
      // parse flags into variables
    }
  });

  if (all) {
    await migrateAll(app, env, source);
  }

  return { app, env, source };
};

const run = async () => {
  try {
    intro();
    checkSettings();
    const { app, env, source } = await parseFlags();
    // continue on here if migrateAll doesn't get called
  } catch (err) {
    complain(err);
  }
};

run();
```